# Adding attribute to an element Javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, selectors-api

I am JavaScript begginer and could use your help with the query below:

I had to find all li placed in nav tag in html. Now I have to check if li has data-direction attribute and if it doesn't - set this attribute to "top". I tried to do it using simple loop, but it doesn't seem to be working - I keep getting info from console that "direction is not defined" so it seems that it doesn't see "data-direction" as an attribute. Maybe I should indicate this attribute differently? Here is my code:

```
   var navLi = document.querySelectorAll("nav li");

   for (i = 0; i < navLi.length; i++) {
       if (navLi[i].data-direction === " ") {
       navLi[i].data-direction = "top";
      }
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute)/[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

```
for (i = 0; i < navLi.length; i++) {
   if ( !navLi[i].hasAttribute('data-direction') ) {
     navLi[i].setAttribute('data-direction', 'top')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute() will return null or an empty string so you need to use the hasAttribute() method to handle the null case.

```
for (var item of document.querySelectorAll("nav li")) {
  if (!item.hasAttribute("data-direction") || item.getAttribute("data-direction").trim() === "") {
    item.setAttribute("data-direction", "top");
  }
}
```